# How can I download an old version of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download, google-chrome-extensions

For testing purposes, I need to download an old version of Google Chrome. I need the stable release of **Google Chrome version 69.0.3497.81** to test some of its features. I need to open it and navigate with it (I think this require turning off the updates).

My system is Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit and it has **Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)**.

I could not find any trusted source to download an old release of Google Chrome from. I find some shady websites with .exe files and I do not want to download from them for security reasons.

Comment: 3rd party link: https://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/history/

Comment: These sites are not trusted. How to ensures that these are not malware? Do you have any idea about these websites source? Are they well known?

Comment: Hence this is a comment not an answer. And you asked for testing purposes.

Comment: Simply go to here: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php , find your os & choose a version, download & install.

Comment: The cypress docker image repo contains many direct links to various versions of Google Chrome, see https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/browsers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Google does not offer older Versions of Chrome, in the name of Security.

You may find older versions on
[The Chromium Project](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium),
although the version may differ slightly on the last number component.

You may have a look at some Chrome clones. For example,
Slimjet is a Webbrowser based on Chrome does provide some older versions of Chrome.
To download visit the
[Slimjet Site](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php)
to access the archive, where I found version 69.0.3497.92 as the closest.

For Chrome/Chromium itself, there are great difficulties in finding
older versions.

Here are some possibilities (which I haven't tried) :

- [Google Chrome 69 offline installers direct download links](https://www.itechtics.com/download-google-chrome-69/)
- [Google Chrome 69.0.3497.81](https://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/87412/)
- [Google Chrome 69.0.3497.92 Stable](https://www.palosoft.com/software/download_google-chrome-69/)
- [Filepuma : Google Chrome (64bit) 69.0.3497.81](https://www.filepuma.com/download/google_chrome_64bit_69.0.3497.81-19986/).
  Verified as clean by [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/fcbbdffe07d6d34f1bbd008e897f81216c9075d3fb7c22ba67d82bd4bbe92e9b/detection).
  Also
  [Google Chrome (32bit) 69.0.3497.81](https://www.filepuma.com/download/google_chrome_32bit_69.0.3497.81-19985/).
  Verified as clean by [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/4fd601486081f60f5628594237baa028895c5b459ec8a290758da5fbaa2dab5c/detection).
- For Ubuntu, you may try the package
  [69.0.3497.81-0ubuntu0](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/69.0.3497.81-0ubuntu0.16.04.1),
  where you may download a `.dsc` file and
  [install the .dsc](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-install-dsc-file-in-linux-896928/)
  from source.

Comment: But if I want to test a feature introduced by Google Chrome Stable release, I need Google Chrome.

Comment: I added some possibilities.

Comment: Is filehippo.com a reputable source? or just found through google search right now. If it is the latter case, these sites may provide malwares. I do not prefer to download from unknown sources. It is very disrespectful from Google to treat users like this. Firefox provide an archive so anyone can freely examine whatever version. I am glad that I am not a user of Chrome.

Comment: Filehippo is a very reputable source and I use it sometimes. Another reputable source in my above list is `chrome-portable.com`. The others I never used.

Comment: Unfortunately `Filehippo` links to google-chrome site which installs the latest version! And `chrome-portable.com` does not have the version 69.0.3497.81

Comment: I think there are some legal problems involved, where Google has disallowed downloading old versions, because other download sites I have visited have similarly referred me to the general Chrome download page. This is why I have counseled using a Chrome clone, not bound by these legalities, or to chrome-portable.com.

Comment: `chrome-portable` does not have the version I want. I

Comment: You might need to settle for close-enough version.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue in that version only. Even slimjet does not offer this version.

Comment: When the situation is that desperate, you might use less-reputable sites. See my last addition to the list.

Comment: The link you provided for Filpuma is only for Windows and I need for Google Chrome for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I added one for Ubuntu,

Comment: +1 @harrymc for Chromium Project suggestion ;)

Comment: Look into PortableApps - Chrome and Iron are there

Comment: I think the Arch Linux community may have found how to install older versions of chrome directly from dl.google.com. Check the sources section of https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-chrome

Answer (score 18):

For Chromium, the best option I've found is https://chromium.cypress.io/. This lets you filter by OS, release channel, and major version, and provides official download links.

Incidentally, if you have a Windows machine, [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) is a nice way to run old versions of Chromium and clean up easily after you're done.

Comment: This was so simple, and the only solution that had the version I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For Chromium Linux/Win/Mac: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bugazelle/chromium-all-old-stable-versions/master/chromium.stable.json

For Chrome - CentOS RPM: http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/RPMS/myrpms/google/

For Chrome - Debain/Ubuntu/Windows/Mac: https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

Answer (score 2):

Using a chromium snapshot should work for most purposes.

Look up the snapshot number from the version number at http://omahaproxy.appspot.com/

Looking up version 69.0.3497.81 returns Base Branch Position 576753.

Go to https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/576753/ and download chrome-linux.zip.

This snapshot is version 69.0.3497.0.

There may not be a snapshot of the exact revision you want so you can go up a directory to https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/, then filter to find a nearby revision.  In this case, there are snapshots of revisions 576751 and 576755 as well.

Answer (score 1):

It can be really hard to find an older version of Chrome as the official website does not allow to download them.  Maybe I do not know how to find them but when I needed an older version I could not find it. 
For now I use this website https://rocketfiles.com/windows/browsers/web-browsers/google-chrome. All versions and builds are available here and you can get them for free.  Also I used some of the ways mentioned above.

You should only remember to download such software only from the safe and Authoritative websites.

Answer (score 1):

**So all of the other answers address Chromium, and not Google Chrome.**

I'm not entirely sure how, but *it seems* like the [Arch Linux community has figured out how to do it](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-chrome).

Checking the sources section of the package, you get a hint from the Arch community on how to do it:

[image: google-chrome sources]

Now, I believe that there aren't a wide variety of architectures that Chrome Supports. In the case of Linux, I believe that amd64 is the only supported arch.

It seems like the only thing you need to do here is replace "stable" with the channel you want, "112.0.5616.165" with the version you want.

Additionally, I would not know what to replace to get that URL to work on Windows or Mac. Also, I don't know if this URL has restrictions on what version you can download from it. **I could not find any documentation on this URL.**

Comment: One thing to note is the dl.google.com links no longer work if the version is more than 14 behind current.

Answer (score 0):

You can download older versions of Chrome from here - https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium

The Google Chrome team doesn't offer older versions to be downloaded for security reasons as someone else pointed out but you might need them for testing so its available from the above page and takes a bit of work to download.

I'd never trust/downloaded from sources like filehippo or anywhere since you can never trust the builds and run them on your machine.

Comment: Google makes old versions available as of June 2023, but it's a bit of a pain: developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing 

In the end, all that hub-bub with puppeteer does is download from a URL like this: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.170/win64/chrome-win64.zip. 

So maybe you can use that to guess at valid URLs. Not all Chrome versions are in there. For example, I had to fetch 115.0.5790.170 instead of .173.