# Chrome and chromedriver version mismatch issue

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am experiencing the below error when i am using chrome (73.0.3683.86) and chromedriver (73.0.3683.68)

Message = "unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:1030\nfrom session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73\n (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)"

I am experiencing the below error when I am using chrome (73.0.3683.86) and chromedriver (2.46.628402) - latest.

Message = "unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:1030\nfrom session not created: Chrome version must be between 71 and 75\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)"

According to the official chromedriver website http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, it should supports for the version 73 and it should not suppose to throw this exception.

so if I go to downgrade the chrome to a specific version which is related to the chrome driver version. Where can I get the setup and how can I downgrade the chrome to the specific (73.0.3683.68) version which is related to the chrome driver. I need it because it is required for some automation purpose.

chrome driver link: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

I have already looked into this query ([How can I download an old version of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1381356/how-can-i-download-an-old-version-of-google-chrome)) where there is no solution for my specific requirement so, I have raised a new query.

Reply to the below-commented user. I am not getting the solution for this issue till now. but you are continuously telling that the solution for this is an issue is given in the linked query where they are telling to use the chromium instead of chrome. because Google has been restricting to use the previous version for chrome due to the security precaution. I could able to understand. But in my case what can I do to resolve the issue.

Kindly share your suggestion.

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/a/1381368/48078

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download an old version of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1381356/how-can-i-download-an-old-version-of-google-chrome)

Comment: I have already looked into this query where there is no solution for my specific requirement so, I have raised a new query.

Comment: What you just posted as a comment should have been edited in the OP to avoid user's flagging it as a dupe.

Comment: i have added this in the description

Comment: "There is no solution" in how far? It says "Google does not offer older Versions of Chrome" and that you may be able to try Chromium. I am not sure what other answer you are expecting.

Comment: This is still a duplicate of an existing question even with your requirement.  You can use an earlier version of ChromeDriver with a newer version of Chrome by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have to match the chromedriver version and the chrome browser version as listed here: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads .
Looking at the error you posted it seems that your chrome version is not detected properly, because 73.x of the webdriver should work with chrome 73.x.

I'm not sure if this error shows if you cannot connect to chrome from the webdriver, so I would check that:
 - you can start chrome by itself from the command line
 - the version is the one you expect it to be
 - chromedriver can start and connect to chrome on the specified port

If you do not have a graphical environment (like in docker) make sure you use the --headless option and if running as root (not recommended) also --no-sandbox.

To get matching versions of the browser and the driver you can do something like:

```
    CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -qO- chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE);
    echo $CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION;
    wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
```