# Error trying to install google chrome on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I tried installing google chrome on my windows 7 32 bit pc, it started working until it stopped and said: error xc0000139. and I don't know about this error and how to fix it, I tried to search in google about this error, but didn't find anything, I need help as fast as possible

Comment: Google Chrome is no longer supported on Windows 7. What version are you trying to install? Did you look for some older offline installer?

Comment: well i tried but it didnt work

Comment: Windows 7 is insecure and dangerous to use.  I have a Windows 7 on another machine and I think Edge runs on it. I do not use Windows 7 any more because of the security issues.

Comment: @legoman890 - You tried what exactly and what exactly didn’t work? [Edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 109 was the last version of Chrome to support Windows 7.

Source : [Sunsetting support for Windows 7 / 8/8.1 and Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 in early 2023](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/185534985/sunsetting-support-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-windows-server-2012-and-2012-r2-in-early-2023?hl=en).

For getting Chrome version 109, see the post
[How can I download an old version of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/1381356/how-can-i-download-an-old-version-of-google-chrome).

After the installation, disable immediately the auto-update option
of chrome.
See the article
[Manage Chrome updates (Windows)](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036?hl=en#zippy=).

Comment: Disabling updates for Chrome isn’t necessary since updates won’t be installed and are not released.

Comment: Downvoting should come with a comment, otherwise it's useless.

Comment: I disagree that downvoting shouldn't be possible without feedback, although feedback is helpful and has been provided.  However, I should point out that while I did provide feedback, I didn't downvote your answer.